# How to correctly loop over each option in a menu and check the value of an attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop over each option of a select menu after it has been click on. Then for each option in the menu I want to read a custom attribute named "data-group" based on it's value I want to either enable or disable that option.

Here is what I have done

```
    $('#MasterWrapUps').click(function (e) {

        var menu = $(this);

        menu.find('option').each(function (index, element) {

            if (customIsAllowed(status, element)) {
                element.attr("disabled", false);
            } else {
                element.attr("disabled", true);
            }

        });

    });

    function customIsAllowed(status, element)
    {
        var status = status.toLowerCase();

        var group = element.attr('data-group');

        if ( group ) {
            group = group.toLowerCase();
        }

        if ( group.indexOf(status) > -1 ){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But my code is giving me an error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'

How can I correctly read the the attribute of each option in the menu I clicked on?

Comment: `element` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object, therefore it doesn't have the `attr()` method. Use either `$(this).attr()` or `$(element).attr()` or `element.getAttribute()` or, since it's a custom data attribute: `element.dataset.group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not getting jquery functions on an element, then it's not a jquery object.  try:

`$(element).attr('data-group')` instead.

Comment: Note that this is safe in all cases; if 'element' is already a jquery object, wrapping it again won't do anything.

Comment: Indeed that worked. I will accept your answer when time permits. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `element` variable in jQuery alias `$`.

```
  $('#MasterWrapUps').click(function (e) {

        var menu = $(this);

        menu.find('option').each(function (index, element) {

            if (customIsAllowed(status, element)) {
                $(element).attr("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $(element).attr("disabled", true);
            }

        });

    });

    function customIsAllowed(status, element)
    {
        var status = status.toLowerCase();

        var group = $(element).attr('data-group');

        if ( group ) {
            group = group.toLowerCase();
        }

        if ( group.indexOf(status) > -1 ){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```